# Extracting every Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN) from a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for the easiest way to extract all the Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN) (a 10-character alphanumeric unique identifier assigned by Amazon.com and its partners for product identification) from a text file and display them one per line.

Example ASIN's include:

```
B00AYR03OC
B00AZ10TIM
B00AZ10TQE
B00AZ10TRI
B00AZ10TUU
B00AZMFUAS
B00B06GF3Y
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its always trivial to extract the string you want but MUCH harder to not extract the strings you don't want so edit your question to show the strings you want extracted IN CONTEXT with the rest of the text you need then extracted from. Post the sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '[A-Z0-9]{10}' file
```

Comment: Don't need pcre: `grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]{10}'` should suffice